# How to append user input to an item in a list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I want user input to be joined to an item in an existing  list

I tried formating the string in the list using %s

```
from random import randint
user_name = input("Name: ")
```

## I want the %s to be the name the user input

```
my_list = ["Hello %s, nice to meet u",  
        "%s! what a wonderful name",
        "welcome %s"]
for m in my_list:
    print(randint(my_list)% user_name)
```

my output should be any of the items in the list accompanied by the user input i.e
   output:
         #Hello Mike, nice to meet u

where "Mike" is the user input

Comment: What do you think `randint(my_list)` does? You should try `choice` from the `random` module instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the logic your code is exhibiting is intended to do, however, here is my interpretation of what you want done.

```
from random import randint

user_name = input("Name: ")

my_list = ["Hello %s, nice to meet u",
        "%s! what a wonderful name",
        "welcome %s"]

print(choice(my_list) % user_name)
```

This will print one of the items from the list (at random) with the input appended in the desired location.

Examples:

```
Name: Tim
Hello Tim, nice to meet u

Name: Pam
Pam! what a wonderful name

Name: Jen
welcome Jen
```

### Edit

Utilize `choice` instead of `randint` for clarity/ease/etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimKlein

Answer (score 2):

I'm more used to using long format strings.

```
from random import choice
user_name = input("Name: ")
my_list = ["Hello {name}, nice to meet u",  
        "{name}! what a wonderful name",
        "welcome {name}"]
for m in my_list:
    print(choice(my_list).format(name=user_name))
```

But changing your `randint` to `choice` should also work in your case.

- `randint` return a random number between min and max
- `choice` randomly choose an element in a list

Comment: @fill_J Make sure to select this as the correct answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think other answers are better but I did the same thing by converting the list to string and then again to list.

```
from random import randint
user_name = input("Name: ")

my_list = ["Hello %s, nice to meet u",  "%s! what a wonderful name", "welcome %s"]

# convert/flatten the list to string
list_to_string =  "::".join(str(x) for x in my_list)

# Replace %s with the username
replaced_string = list_to_string.replace("%s",user_name )

# convert string to list 
string_to_list = replaced_string.split("::")

print(string_to_list)
```

Comment: What is the OP add a string with :: inside? That sounds like a dangerous method. At least, use list comphrensions to do something like `[s.replace("%s", user_name) for s in my_list]`

Comment: `::` is just a place holder so that I can convert the `string` back to `list`. But, your answer is much better with the computation.